# Regex match three words in order (there can be words in between)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm converting a buffer of a PDF into a string to find the page count. Here is an example of the buffer string:

```
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 2
/Kids[4 0 R 8 0 R]
>>
```

I see that page count is defined after `/Type /Pages` and after `/Count`. Here is a different example:

```
<<
/Type /Pages
/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]
/Count 22
>>
```

As you can see, the count is now defined after `MediaBox` in between. I am trying to come up with a regex statement that can match the page count in both scenarios but I'm not sure where to start.
Would it make sense to match for 3 words in order then extract the number? Matching `Type` first, then `Pages`, then lastly `Count` and extract the number after?

Comment: Thank you so much @CarySwoveland, if you post as an answer I will accept it :)

Comment: As per your request I've offered an answer but please hold off selecting an answer for at least a couple of hours to see what else you get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a regex which looks for `/Type` and `/Pages` between `<<` and `>>` and then captures the `Count` when they are both found. This will then be completely independent of the order of the tags. You can do this with a [tempered greedy token](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed) which prevents matching beyond `>>`:

```
<<(?=(?:(?!>>).)*\/Type)(?=(?:(?!>>).)*\/Pages)(?:(?!>>).)*\/Count\s+(\d+)
```

For sample data of:

```
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 2
/Kids[4 0 R 8 0 R]
>>
<<
/Type /Pages
/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]
/Count 22
>>
<<
/Type /Image
/MediaBox [ 0 0 612 792 ]
/Count 1
>>
1 0 obj <</Type /Pages /Kids [3 0 R ] /Count 1 >>
2 0 obj <<   /Count 1   /Kids [ 5 0 R ]   /Type /Pages >>
```

Group 1 will contain `[2, 22, 1, 1]`

Demo on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/iWIN1P/1). Note you need the `s` regex flag to make `.` match newlines as well.

Comment: This works perfect as well and also works whether there is a new line or space.

Answer (score 3):

```
/\/Type \/Pages\b.*?^\/Count (\d+)/ms
```

should do it, with capture group 1 holding the value of the count.

Demo(https://regex101.com/r/5dk3eP/1). Hover the cursor over each element of the regular expression to obtain an explanation of its function.

Comment: RJK, you may wish to consider editing your question to address @KJ's comment. I know nothing of the structure of PDF files. I merely addressed your two examples in my answer.

Comment: @KJ, I intend to delete my answer in favour of Nick's. Before doing so you may wish to move your comment to the question.

Comment: @CarySwoveland I wouldn't delete. If OP controls their PDF such that the elements are always in order, this solution will be far more efficient than mine.

Comment: My PDFs will always be from the same source so the format and header should widely stay the same, but I suppose it's good to stay flexible

Comment: That's a good point @KJ thanks for bringing it up and helping me